# Sending Selected Data to Server

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to send data to the server, the numbers listed in select TAG are event id's already on the server, Can someone show me how to solve this ?

2) Server side will return a JSON response of one of three types:

{"status":"ok"} // when request satisfied

{"status":"partial", "reserved": n} // when request is partially satisfied, where n is a number of reserved tickets.

{"status":"failed"} // when there are no tikets available.

**How to show the number of tickets booked on the screen ?**

```
<h1>Current Events Tickets:</h1>

<p>FHSU marching band concert <b>Ticket ID:6761</b></p>
<p>Great Bend Film Festival <b>Ticket ID:454</b></p>
<p>HPPR fundraising <b>Ticket ID:778</b></p>
<p>Monarch Butterflies watching Chayenne Bottoms<b>Ticket ID:234</b></p>

<form id="register"  action=" http://guimon.info/js/tickets.php" method="post">



<h2>Register Your Tickets</h2>

<label for="name"> Username </label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
<label for="email"> Email </label> <input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
<label for="event_id">
<select>
  <option value="6761">FHSU marching band concert</option>
  <option value="454">Great Bend Film Festival</option>
  <option value="778">HPPR fundraising Ticket ID</option>
  <option value="234">Monarch Butterflies watching Chayenne Bottoms</option>
</select>
  </label> 
<label for="number_of_tickets"> No of Ticekts </label> <input type="text" id="number_of_tickets" name="number_of_tickets"/>

<input type="submit" value="Join"/>
</form>

<Script>
$('#register').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var details=$('#register').serialize();
    $.post(' http://guimon.info/js/tickets.php',details,function(data)
    {
        $('#register').html(data);
    });
});


</Script>
```

Comment: can you describe what actions you want to take when you get different responses?

Comment: Show on the screen , if there is any ticket booked

Comment: be more specific? According to your request, the response is only returning status, and reserved.

Comment: i.e After the post, you could inquire if data.status == ok, then do this. otherwise if data.status == partial do that.

Comment: If status is reserved show the number of tickets you entered are reserved , can you show me how to to do it ?

Comment: Let me do some coding!

Comment: I posted an answer. The result is displaying an alert. Let me know where do you want to display the html.

Comment: I want to display it below the form , but my first issue the select tag, how to solve that ?

Comment: I just update my answer

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: It says invalid form

Comment: server or client side error?

Comment: I think client side error.

Comment: ok. in what line of your code? have you debug/console.log

Comment: Also, I think you are posting twice. In  your form you have action= http://guimon.info/js/tickets.php and then posting again the same php program using `$.post`

Comment: I have spend Hours I don't know why it's not working cant you show me how ? or fix it

Comment: i'm going to create a test php program. Give me some time

Answer (score 0):

Change your select to `<select id="event">`

```
$(function(){

   $('#register').on('submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var details=$('#register').serialize();
     console.log(details)
     $.post('phpResponse.php', details, function(data)
     {
        console.log(data);
        var event = $('option:selected').text();
        var ticket = $('#event').val();
        $('#results').html("<p>"+event+" <b>TicketID: "+ticket+"</p>");

     });
   });
});
```

Insert a div tag at the end of the form to display the results:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

PHP test code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

    $data = array('status' => 'ok', 'reserved' => 4);
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/reservation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Current Events Tickets:</h1>
<div id="results">
</div>

<form id="register"  action="#" method="post">

<h2>Register Your Tickets</h2>

<label for="name"> Username </label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
<label for="email"> Email </label> <input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
<label for="event_id">
<select id="event">
  <option value="6761">FHSU marching band concert</option>
  <option value="454">Great Bend Film Festival</option>
  <option value="778">HPPR fundraising Ticket ID</option>
  <option value="234">Monarch Butterflies watching Chayenne Bottoms</option>
</select>
  </label> 
<label for="number_of_tickets"> No of Ticekts </label> <input type="text" id="number_of_tickets" name="number_of_tickets"/>

<input type="submit" value="Join"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working for me! I created a small php program to return the result and display the data without any problem.

Comment: @UmarSatti: change your form action to `action="#"`

Comment: Can you upload the file and share link , it's giving me invalid form error

Comment: Don't know how to upload the file here!

Comment: Sorry, man gotta go to bed! I think I gave u everything you need to fix your problem!